# The (global) theory of Borel equivalence relations

Tags: lo.logic, descriptive-set-theory

What do we know about the complexity of the theory of Borel equivalence relations, with the Borel reducibility order $\leq_B$?

That is, let $\mathcal{B}$ be the set of all Borel equivalence relations on your favorite uncountable Polish space, modulo bireducibility. What is the complexity of the first order theory of $(\mathcal{B},\leq_B)$? Is it known to be undecidable?

A result of Louveau-Velickovic (*A note on Borel Equivalence Relations*, PAMS, 1994) shows that $(\mathcal{P}(\omega),\subseteq^*)$ embeds into $(\mathcal{B},\leq_B)$, and thus so does any partial order of size $\leq\aleph_1$. Does this provide an answer to my question?

Comment: I don’t know much about $\mathcal B$ to answer the main question, however the mere fact that it contains $(\mathcal P(\omega),\subseteq^*)$ does not imply anything: $(\mathcal P(\omega),\subseteq^*)$ is an atomless Boolean algebra, hence its theory is decidable.

Comment: That is, it does not imply anything about the complexity of the full first-order theory of $\mathcal B$. It does imply the decidability of universal sentences (and their Boolean combinations).

Comment: A related question would be: what is known about the rigidity of $\cal B$?

Comment: @Burak: No. This is again decidable (whether it’s all sets or Borel sets makes no difference). In general, in order to show undecidability, one shouldn’t look for large but orderly substructures like Boolean algebras, but rather for small and combinatorially peculiar substructures. Preferably definable.

Comment: Would it help to know that there exists an assignment of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ to countable Borel equivalence relations $B \mapsto E_B$ such that $B \subseteq C \leftrightarrow E_B \leq_B E_C$, see [here Theorem 3.3](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~greg/223b.1.06s/borel.pdf)? For a second I thought this was true for all subsets and posted a faulty comment, but let me add this anyway.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: In any case, I'll keep the comment here since it provides us more information, compared to the embedding written in the question, about the rich structure of $\leq_B$.

Comment: At least the Louveau-Velickovic's result implies the $\Sigma_1$-theory of $(\mathcal{B},\leq_B)$ is decidable.